# I want to populate the employeeData with the new data from req.body in my server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to populate **req.body** from a function using the function parameter to perform the update but it's not working. Below are my code

data-service.js

```
var employees = [];
//Here is a function that populate the employees array
function initialize() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile('./data/employees.json', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                try {
                    employees = JSON.parse(data);
                    resolve(employees);
                } catch (err) {
                    reject('Unable to read file');
                }
            }
        });
        fs.readFile('./data/departments.json', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                try {
                    departments = JSON.parse(data);
                    resolve(departments);
                } catch (err) {
                    reject('Unable to read file');
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Here is the function to perform update if the id matches the id of the employee in the array

```
function updateEmployee(employeeData) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const newData = [];
            employees.forEach((element) => {
                if (element.employeeNum == employeeData.employeeNum) {
                   //Here I want to populate the employeeData with the new data from req.body in my server.js
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Here route that handles the update in the server.js

```
app.post('/employee/update', (req, res) => {
    dataService.updateEmployee(req.body).then(function(data) {
        res.redirect("/employees");
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: What is not working? For now, you are just searching the employee, but don't to anything with the received data. Furthermore, your promise never resolves, so your route never reaches the `res.redirect()`

Comment: Furthermore, your initialization has a race condition. You have one promise, but you are asynchonously reading two files. One of the files will be handled first, then the promise resolves (either with employees or departmens, whatever finished first) or rejects. You won't get a resolve or reject for the other file. I would suggest using something like `Promise.all()` and make the initialization of each file a promise of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /Here I want to populate the employeeData with the new data from req.body in my server.js

That doesn't make sense. `req.body` is the body of the **request** coming into your server. It makes sense to modify `employee` (the object you have in the `employees` array) with the data from `employeeData`, but not the other way around. Something like:

```
function updateEmployee(employeeData) {
    // Not clear why you're using a promise here, but I assume it's to
    // emulate some storage update that would be asynchronous...
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const newData = [];
            for (const employee of employees) {
                if (employee.employeeNum == employeeData.employeeNum) {
                   // Perhaps
                   employeePropertyNames.forEach(name => {
                       // There may be a couple you want 
                       if (employeeData.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                           element[name] = employeeData[name];
                       }
                   });
                   // Or: Object.assign(employee, employeeData); -- But NOT A GOOD IDEA
                   resolve(employee);
                   break;
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
}
```

...where `employeePropertyNames` is a list of the names of the properties of employees that you want to allow to be updated by client request.

Using a blind `Object.assign` isn't a good idea because it lets the client request make any change it wants (including adding entirely new properties), where presumably somethings (like `employeeNum`) shouldn't be changed.

Comment: Thanks. It worked, I got your explanation and I have refactor my code to work better.